# Proof for bounding a function in two variables, one real and one integer

Tags: real-analysis, functions, optimization

I would like to proof that the function $f(x,k)=2xk^{-4x^2}$, where $x$ is a real variable and $k$ is an integer variable, is always smaller than $1$ for all $k>2$ and all $x \ge 0$.

This is my solution. Using the first derivative of $f(x,k)$ with respect to $x$, I found that $f(x,k)$ is maximised by $x=\sqrt{2}{(4\log_e k)^{-1/2}}$. Then it is easy to show that $f(\sqrt{2}{(4\log_e k)^{-1/2}},k)$ is always smaller than $1$ for all $k>2$.

Is this approach correct to solve this problem?

Thank you! 
M.

Comment: You say, '$k<1$ for all k>2'...

Comment: If you use the derivative test, then you only find relative max. You need some extra to verified the absolute max.

Comment: Thank you. "[...]  is always smaller than $1$" refers to $f(x,k)$ in the problem text. $k > 2$ is the $k$'s constraint. What "extra" are you referring? The function decreases when the integer variable $k$ increases, right? Since $k > 2$, could I then simply find the maximum of $f(x,3)$?

Comment: I just have to prove that $f(x,k)$ is always smaller than $1$ for all $k>2$ and $x \ge 0$.